# No llego a entender porque mi script no esta correctamente implementado en el HTML, ¿Qué podría estar pasando?

Tags: javascript, html, script, screen

Este es el script

```
function getFullscreenElement() {
    return document.fullscreenElement
        || document.webkitFullscreenElement
        ||document.mozFullscreenElement
        ||document.msFullscreenElement;
        
    
}
document.addEventListener("dbclick",()=>{
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen().catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Y tiene esta localización dentro de mi HTML.Cuando accedo a la consola de Firefox "document.log(e)" es null.

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
    <!-- primero jQuery, despu?s Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="FotoPanComp.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Un código bien indentado es mil veces más fácil de corregir que tener que andar haciendo scroll para ver dónde está cada parte de tu función... Además, *mi código no funciona* no es un error que nos ayude a saber qué pasa! Especifica un poco, y de paso te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para que veas cómo funcionamos y te ganes tus primeras medallas

Comment: Saludos. Coloca (no alcanzo a notar) el error que te esta saliendo o si el resultado obtenido no es el esperado igual coloca que obtienes y que debieras obtener.

Comment: La primera función parece no necesitarse para nada.

Comment: tu error se da porque es `dblclick` no  `dbclick` como notas te falta un `L`